# Can't deploy cloud function with vpc serverless connector

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, vpc

I've configured a network to use a static IP for egress traffic using a serverless VPC access.

I was able to test with a simple function:

```
exports.echo = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': 'https://postman-echo.com/ip',
 };
  request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    res.json(JSON.parse(response.body));
  });
})
```

It works returning the same IP I've configured.

But when I try to deploy the actual function I want to use the egress settings, I get an `undefined` error:

```
$ gcloud functions deploy sendTransaction --vpc-connector vault-connector --egress-settings all
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.                                                                                                                                                
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs
```

The logs aren't very helpful:

```
$ gcloud functions logs read sendTransaction
sendTransaction      2020-08-09 20:51:18.909  Provided module can't be loaded.
sendTransaction      2020-08-09 20:51:18.909  Is there a syntax error in your code?
sendTransaction      2020-08-09 20:51:18.909  Detailed stack trace: undefined
sendTransaction      2020-08-09 20:51:18.910  Could not load the function, shutting down.
sendTransaction      2020-08-09 20:51:19.760  Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Function cannot be initialized.
```

No stack trace. It could be a syntax error, as the logs suggest, but the exact same function is correctly deployed through firebase cli:

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions:sendTransaction

=== Deploying to 'xxxx'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (805.19 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: current functions in project: sendTransaction(us-central1)
i  functions: uploading functions in project: sendTransaction(us-central1)
i  functions: updating Node.js 12 function sendTransaction(us-central1)...
i  scheduler: ensuring required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  pubsub: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  scheduler: required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  pubsub: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: scheduler job firebase-schedule-sendTransaction-us-central1 is up to date, no changes required
✔  functions[sendTransaction(us-central1)]: Successful update operation. 

✔  Deploy complete!
```

It's worth mentioning this is a pub/sub triggered function.

Are there known incompatibilities between deploying with firebase cli and gcloud cli that could cause such behavior?

Edit: adding the output of the flag `--verbosity debug` as suggested:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 983, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 808, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/functions/deploy.py", line 352, in Run
    return _Run(args, track=self.ReleaseTrack())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/functions/deploy.py", line 304, in _Run
    api_util.WaitForFunctionUpdateOperation(
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/util.py", line 318, in CatchHTTPErrorRaiseHTTPExceptionFn
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/util.py", line 367, in WaitForFunctionUpdateOperation
    operations.Wait(op, client.MESSAGES_MODULE, client, _DEPLOY_WAIT_NOTICE,
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 150, in Wait
    _WaitForOperation(client, request, notice, try_set_invoker,
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 113, in _WaitForOperation
    retryer.RetryOnResult(_GetOperationStatus,
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 219, in RetryOnResult
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 73, in _GetOperationStatus
    raise exceptions.FunctionsError(OperationErrorToString(op.error))
```

Comment: The logs are indeed not helpful, try using the `--verbosity debug` flag on the deploy command to check if more details arise from it. Let me know the results.

Comment: Right, @ralemos, I updated the question to include the output.

Comment: Also, I'm gonna try to reinstall my cloud sdk https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/r7mADCM4LNg

Comment: This error could mean one of two things, either that billing is not enabled to your project, you can check how to enable it [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#enable_billing_for_a_project), or that there is a file missing or not with a proper name, please double check the file names and also if you have a `.gcloudignore` check it's content to make sure that your deploy is not ignoring any relevant files.

Comment: Ok... billing is enabled (there are other functions in the same projects), .gloudignore looks ok (just ignoring git files and node_modules) and it doesn't seem to be a reference or syntax problem, because the same function deploys successfully through firebase cli... also a simpler function deploys just fine with the vpc. Don't know what else it could be.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was related to environment variables. Firebase and gcloud deployments don't share env vars, you need to pass along your env vars when deploying with gcloud.